# Использование асинхронных функций в магических методах

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, async-await, asyncio

У меня есть класс, предназначенный для работы с mysql:

```
class MySQL:
    def __init__(
        self,
        password: str,
        database: str,
        loop: asyncio.get_event_loop,
        host: str = 'localhost',
        port: int = 3306,
        user: str = 'root',
    ):
        self.pool = await aiomysql.create_pool(host = host, port = port, user = user,
                                           password = password, db = database, loop = loop)

        self.cursor = self.pool.acquire().cursor()
```

Как уже можно было понять, функция aiomysql.create_pool() - асинхронная. Но вот незадача, асинхронные функции нельзя использовать в магических методах. Как в этой ситуации быть?

Comment: в каких методах?

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так можно запустить Ваш код:

```
class MySQL:
    def __init__(
        self,
        password: str,
        database: str,
        loop: asyncio.get_event_loop,
        host: str = 'localhost',
        port: int = 3306,
        user: str = 'root',
    ):

        def on_connection(task):
            loop.create_task(task.result().cursor()).add_done_callback(
                lambda task: self.cursor = task.result() )

        def on_pool(task):
            self.pool = task.result()
            loop.create_task(self.pool.acquire()).add_done_callback(on_connection)

        loop.create_task(
            aiomysql.create_pool(
                host = host,
                port = port, 
                user = user,                                           
                password = password,
                db = database,
                loop = loop).add_done_callback(on_pool)
```

Но курсор не будет доступен сразу после инициализации, только после нескольких await в коде, которые длятся дольше чем нужно для коннекта.

Вместо этого разделите инициализацию класса и подключение:

```
class MySQL:
    def __init__(
        self,
        password: str,
        database: str,
        loop: asyncio.get_event_loop,
        host: str = 'localhost',
        port: int = 3306,
        user: str = 'root',
    ): 
       self.pool = None
       self.connect_args = dict(
                host = host,
                port = port, 
                user = user,                                           
                password = password,
                db = database,
                loop = loop)

    async def connect(self):
        self.pool = await aiomysql.create_pool(** self.connect_args)

    async def get_cursor(self)
        return await (await self.pool.acquire()).cursor()
```

И класс в коде используется

```
    my = MySQL(....)
    await my.connect()
    cursor = await my.get_cursor()
```